# Animate div elements sequentially with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a few `div` elements that are nested in a `div` with the class `.menu`; the idea is to transition each element into the page from the outer edges sequentially from top to bottom. I thought I could accomplish this with `:nth-child(n)` but for some reason I can't get it to work with the positions. I had transitions working just fine with just `transition: 1s left/right`. However, I decided I wanted a delay between each initial transition to achieve a nice visual effect. I went to [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) and looked into using the `animation` feature of `CSS` and decided I needed the following:

```
.menu div { position: relative; }
.menu:nth-child(0) {
    left: 60%;
    animation: 1s transitionLeft forwards;
}
.menu:nth-child(1) {
    right: 60%;
    animation: 1s transitionRight forwards;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes transitionLeft { 100% { left: 0; } }
@keyframes transitionRight { 100% { right: 0; } }
```

I don't believe this is working the way I expect it to as I don't get any animation at all; this may have something to do with the nesting of `.main->div:a, div:a, …`. Below is the current code for this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu {
  transition: 1s all;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.menu > h1 {
  transition: 1s all;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 10vw;
  margin: 2% 0 0 0;
}
.menu a {
  transition: 0.25s all;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 3vw;
}
.menu div { position: relative; }
.menu div:nth-child(0) {
  left: 60%;
  animation-name: transitionLeft;
  animation: 1s transitionLeft forwards;
}
.menu div:nth-child(1) {
  right: 60%;
  animation: 1s transitionRight forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes transitionLeft { 100% { left: 0; } }
@keyframes transitionRight { 100% { right: 0; } }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h1>Perpetual J Studios</h1>
  <div><a href="#">About</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Games</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Software</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Apps</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Academy</a></div>
</div>
```

I was able to get `transition: 1s left/right` to work on `.main div:nth-child(odd/even)` but not `.main:nth-child(odd/even)`. Why is that?

---

The primary focus of this question is how should I properly transition my elements from the outer edges of the screen in `L, R, L, R, L, R` order? If you feel like giving some advice in your answer:

- What are some potential *gotchas* with this approach?

  - Aside from ensuring I use cross-browser tags such as `webkit`.
- What are a few points I should think of in regards to this behavior?

Comment: Well that would definitely explain why `main:nth-child` doesn't work but `main div:nth-child` does.

Comment: @TylerRoper That's my fault since I come from a `C#` background where indices are zero based. I did try using `1` based but that didn't work either.

Comment: @TylerRoper Turns out that was the issue; swapped to starting at `2` and it works now; if you write up an answer I can give credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to note:

1. `.menu:nth-child(1)` would be looking for a `class="menu"` element that is the very first child of its parent. Without your context, I can't tell if this exists, but it's likely not what you want in this case.
2. `nth-child()` starts at `1`, not `0`.
3. `div:nth-child(1)` will only apply to `<div>` elements that are the first child of their parent. If you take a look at your HTML, none of your `<div>` elements are the first child of their parent. You can start at `div:nth-child(2)` instead.
4. You can pull out some of the common stuff and put it in an `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` to avoid so much repitition.

Tidying that up, you might be looking at something like the code below. (I've minified the bulk of your CSS that I haven't touched, just to make it a bit more clear what I changed)

```css
.menu,.menu>h1{transition:1s all}body{background-color:#222;color:#fff}.menu{text-align:center;overflow:hidden;padding-bottom:5%}.menu>h1{cursor:default;font-size:10vw;margin:2% 0 0}.menu a{transition:.25s all;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;margin:10px 0;font-size:3vw}.menu div{position:relative}@keyframes transitionLeft{100%{left:0}}@keyframes transitionRight{100%{right:0}}

.menu div:nth-child(odd) {       
  right: 60%;
  animation: 1s transitionRight forwards;
}

.menu div:nth-child(even) {
  left: 60%;
  animation: 1s transitionLeft forwards;
}

.menu div:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 0.5s; }
.menu div:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 1.0s; }
.menu div:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 1.5s; }
.menu div:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: 2.0s; }
.menu div:nth-child(7) { animation-delay: 2.5s; }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h1>Perpetual J Studios</h1>
  <div><a href="#">About</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Games</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Software</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Apps</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Academy</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PerpetualJ Not a problem. Please take note of my edit, making use of `odd` and `even`. Makes the code a little cleaner/easier :)